# ¿Como hago que un objeto siga a otro mientras se mueve con phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, motor-de-juego, phaser3

Estoy haciendo el tipico juego de la culebrita pero que el cuerpo de la culebra siga el mouse y para eso tengo este metodo

```
for (let index = 1; index < snake.length; index++) {
        this.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {
            this.physics.moveToObject(sna, pointer, 200);
            this.physics.moveToObject(snake[index], snake[index - 1], 200);
        }, this);
    }
```

basicamente esto hace que mientras se mueva el mouse todos los nuevos cuadrantes del cuerpo de la serpiente se sigan entre ellos, pero una vez que detengo el mouse se destruye el cuerpo, he investigado y encontre que existen los metodos de objetos

```
scene.input.on('gameobjectdown', function(pointer, gameObject, event){ /* ... */ });
scene.input.on('gameobjectup', function(pointer, gameObject, event){ /* ... */ });
scene.input.on('gameobjectmove', function(pointer, gameObject, event){ /* ... */ });
scene.input.on('gameobjectover', function(pointer, gameObject, event){ /* ... */ });
scene.input.on('gameobjectout', function(pointer, gameObject, event){ /* ... */ });
```

[Fuente](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/touchevents/)

Quisiera saber como implementar el evento gameobjectmove de manera que se sigan constantemente las piezas y no solo cuando se mueva el mouse pero no se como

Comment: No se destruye, quedan todas las partes solapadas porque terminan en el mismo punto y se mueven a la misma velocidad hacia el puntero.

Comment: Con destruir me refería a que dejan de estar en fila como una serpiente y los pedazos pasan a moverse en vectores fijos cuando dejo de mover el mouse

Comment: `moveToObject` se debe interrumpir cada vez que se vuelve a llamar en cada vuelta del main loop, sino tardaría delta*200*(el tiempo durante el que estuvo el puntero en movimiento a 60fps)... si hubiesen sido dos segundos serían más de cinco minutos, según mis estimaciones. Como no se termina de ejecutar produce la ilusión de que no sigue vectores fijos. Yo almacenaría el recorrido del puntero en una pila, pero probablemente el framework provea alguna solución mejor.